# Error with a list in a table

Tags: tables, itemize, landscape

I like to create a table in `landscape` format that has a list in one column. I have taken `tabulary` for the table and `itemize` for the list. When compiling, I get the following error: "`Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \end{tabulary}`"
I have updated MiKTeX and used other compilers (e.g. overleaf). The error occurs everywhere. Does anyone have an idea how I can fix this?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}
    \newgeometry{margin=1cm}
    \begin{landscape}
            \begin{tabulary}{1.4\textwidth}{|L|L|L|L|}
            \hline
            \bfseries{Name}& \bfseries{mögliche Fragen} & \bfseries{Beschreibung} & \bfseries{Link/Quelle} \\
            \hline \hline
            UCDP &{\begin{itemize}
                    \item Ist durch Konflikte die Flächennutzung eine andere?
                    \item Haben Konflikte Auswirkungen auf die Waldfläche?
            \end{itemize}}& Uppsala Conflict Data Program. Es ist eine Sammlung zu allen Konflikten weltweit.& \url{https://ucdp.uu.se/encyclopedia}\\
            \hline
        \end{tabulary}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

**Edit**:
The package `tabulary` with its column specification is not the right choice for inserting lists as you do. Try to use `tabularx` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabularx}%
{
\setlist[itemize]{nosep,
                  label=\textbullet,
                  leftmargin=*,
                  after=\end{minipage},
                  before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
                  }
}

\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
%    \newgeometry{margin=1cm}
    \begin{landscape}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{| l | L | L| l |} 
    \Xhline{1pt}
\thead{Name}    
        &   \thead{Mögliche Fragen}
            &   \thead{Beschreibung} 
                &   \thead{Link/Quelle}     \\
    \Xhline{0.6pt}
UCDP    &   \begin{itemize}
        \item Ist durch Konflikte die Flächennutzung eine andere?
        \item Haben Konflikte Auswirkungen auf die Waldfläche?
            \end{itemize}
            &   Uppsala Conflict Data Program. Es ist eine Sammlung zu allen Konflikten weltweit.
                & \url{https://ucdp.uu.se/encyclopedia}\\
    \Xhline{1pt}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or `tabularray` package as is used in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tblr}%
{
\setlist[itemize]{nosep,
                  label=\textbullet,
                  leftmargin=*,
                  after=\end{minipage},
                  before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
                  }
}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, varwidth}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
%    \newgeometry{margin=1cm}
    \begin{landscape}
\centering
\begin{tblr}{vlines,
             colspec={l X[l] X[l] l},
             row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
             measure=vbox
             }
    \toprule
Name    &   Mögliche Fragen 
            &   Beschreibung  
                &   Link/Quelle     \\
    \midrule
UCDP    &   \begin{itemize}
        \item Ist durch Konflikte die Flächennutzung eine andere?
        \item Haben Konflikte Auswirkungen auf die Waldfläche?
            \end{itemize}
            &   Uppsala Conflict Data Program. Es ist eine Sammlung zu allen Konflikten weltweit.
                & \url{https://ucdp.uu.se/encyclopedia}\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast solution. I use tabularx now. Works well! :)